# How to add SASS support to storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, storybook

I have a Vue application created with Vue Cli and I'm trying to put sass support inside my storybook but I'm receiving this error when I run the storybook:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/atoms/TinyMCE/TinyMCE.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4762223c&scoped=true&lang=scss (./node_modules/vue-docgen-loader/lib??ref--12!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist??ref--3!./src/components/atoms/TinyMCE/TinyMCE.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4762223c&scoped=true&lang=scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (C:\trabalho\repositories\mb-redesign-front\node_modules\style-loader\dist\index.js:19:24)
```

My main.js file of storybook is configurated with webpackFinal according the docs of storybook:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme",
  ],

  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-3-mb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@etchteam/storybook-addon-css-variables-theme": "^1.0.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3",
    "@wiris/mathtype-tinymce5": "^7.27.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "phosphor-vue": "^4.3.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^6.3.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
  }
}
```

And this is the style tag of my component with error:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
  .TinyMCE {
    .tox .tox-tbtn:focus:not(.tox-tbtn--disabled) {
      color: $gray-dark !important;
      svg {
        fill: $gray-dark !important;
      }
    }
    .tox-tinymce {
      border: 1px solid $cinza-light !important;
      border-radius: $border-radius-1 !important;
    }
    .tox:not([dir="rtl"]) .tox-toolbar__group:not(:last-of-type) {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
      border-right: 0;
    }
    .tox-editor-header {
      background-color: $gray-subtle !important;
    }
    .tox-toolbar__primary {
      background-color: $gray-subtle !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-light !important;
      background: $gray-subtle !important;
    }
    .mce-content-body > p {
      font-family: "Roboto" !important;
    }
    button {
      .tox-icon {
        svg {
          fill: $gray-dark;
        }
        i {
          font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
      }
      &:focus {
        svg {
          fill: $gray-dark;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```